# Numbers lists in LaTeX

Tags: lists, pgfmath

I would like to create something like `a=array[1,2,15,6,18]` and then `a[0]=1, a[1]=2`. Is it possible to create an array in LaTeX (with `pgf` or another package)?

Comment: Probably, but you'll most likely have to use a different syntax.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What would be the usage of such arrays? What are you thinking to store in them?

Comment: I am a teacher and I would like to store the number of points for each exercise at the beginning of my document. For exemple \points=[5,2,8] would mean that the first exercise has a value of 5 points, the second exercise has a value of 2 points...
In my document, I would then have something like: Exercise 1 (\points[0] points)

Answer (score 5):

The package `listofitems` is designed for that. Here is a small example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\readlist*\myarray{1,2,15, lalala, 6,18}
\myarray[3]

\myarray[]

\textcolor{Tomato}{\textsf{\myarray[-3]}} = \textcolor{Tomato}{\textsf{\myarray[4]}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**PGF**

Here is how you use arrays with the [pgfmath](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfmath}
\newcommand\Arr[1]{#1 $\mapsto $ \pgfmathparse{\myarray[#1]}\pgfmathresult}

\begin{document}
\def\myarray{{1,2,15,6,18}}

  \Arr{0},
  \Arr{1},
  \Arr{2},
  \Arr{3},
  \Arr{4},

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

In particular, pgfmath arrays are 0-based (i.e. the indexing starts from 0). For more details search for "array operators" in the [pgf](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) manual (section 89.2, page 927 for version 3.0.1a).

**LaTeX3**

Here is how you can define and access array-like variables using [xparse/expl3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/interface3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% Usage: \DefineArray{array name}{data as comma separate list}
\NewDocumentCommand\DefineArray{ mm }{
  \seq_new:c {l_internal_array_#1_seq}% define an array/sequence
  \seq_set_from_clist:cn{l_internal_array_#1_seq}{#2}% set array
}
% Usage: \Array{array name}{index}
\NewDocumentCommand\Array{ mm }{
  #2 $\mapsto$ \seq_item:cn{l_internal_array_#1_seq}{#2}
}
% As clemens says in the comments, for real use the following is better:
% \NewExpandableDocumentCommand\Array{ \seq_item:cn{l_internal_array_#1_seq}{#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

    \DefineArray{myarray}{1,2,15,6,18}

    \Array{myarray}{3},
    \Array{myarray}{1},
    \Array{myarray}{4},
    \Array{myarray}{2}.

\end{document}
```

The output in this case is:

[image]

In particular, these arrays are 1-based. This is using the "sequence" data-type from expl3. See Part VIII of the interface3 manual for more information.

Comment: The output for the second example is “15, 1, 6, 2.”. In case of the second example you could also use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\Array` because `\seq_item:Nn` is expandable. This might or might not be useful depending on the use case of the OP

Comment: @clemens Thanks, I guess I changed the macro after I posted the code - I've fixed up the post to agree with the stated output. I agree, using, `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\` is better.

Comment: Although I would argue as soon as it expands to stuff like `$\mapsto$` the macro being expandable is dangerous again… :)