# Indexing variables

Tags: variable

Is it possible to create variables that can be defined using integers. I would create an example to work with but I have no idea how to start. Hopefully the snippet I have included makes sense.

```
% creates variables wk[1], wk[2], ... , wk[10]
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,10}{\newcommand\wk[\i]{}} 

% stores the value 'this is week 2' into \wk[2]
\wk[2]{this is week 2}

% outputs 'this is week 2'
\wk[2]
```

Comment: It would help if you stated the objective of this project; e.g., what you're trying to do with the elements of the `wk` string vector. It would also help if you stated which TeX engine you use: pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, or something else?

Comment: Probably related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/395752/numbers-lists-in-latex/395766#395766

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables?

(La)TeX is a macro language with macro-expansion/replacement.

You have macros, registers and parameters.

You can use macros that don't process arguments as variables.

In any case you need to be aware of how macro-expansion works and about the order in time in which single expansion-steps and assignments are carried out.

I'd just use a macro `\name` which takes a sequence of tokens nested in curly braces for the name of a control-sequence-token and via `\csname..\endcsname` constructs/delivers that control-sequence-token while leaving things in place that possibly occur between `\name` and the opening-curly-brace.
That control-sequence-token in turn can be (re)defined to be a macro or can be expanded, just as you like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\name{}\long\def\name#1#{\romannumeral0\innername{#1}}%
\newcommand\innername[2]{%
  \expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\csname #2\endcsname}{0 #1}%
}%
\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}%

% This loop defines macros/control-word-tokens \wk[1], \wk[2], ... , \wk[10] 
% with "empty" replacement-text:
\foreach \i in {1,2,...,10}{%
   \name\newcommand*{wk[\i]}{}%
   % \foreach opens up a local scope. 
   % Thus we need to turn assignments restricted to that scope into global 
   % assignments:
   \name\name\global\let{wk[\i]}={wk[\i]}%
} %

\begin{document}

% This "stores the value 'this is week 2' into \wk[2]".
% Better: This redefines the macro \wk[2] to expand to the phrase "this is week 2".
\name\renewcommand*{wk[2]}{this is week 2}

% As there is nothing between \name and the opening brace, this just delivers the
% control-sequence-token \wk[2] which in turn gets expanded as usual while that
% expansion yields 'this is week 2':
\name{wk[2]}

% If eTeX-extensions are available, you can use \number\numexpr.. for calculations:
\name{wk[\number\numexpr(2*3)-5+1\relax]}

% this shows the definition/meaning of \wk[2] on the screen/in the .log-file:
%\name\show{wk[2]}

% this prints the meaning of \wk[2]
\texttt{\name\string{wk[2]}: \name\meaning{wk[2]}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, this is great. I particularly like the commenting.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple version that makes use of the `xparse` package to define a new array-like command with a first parameter in square brackets and an optional second parameter in braces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand\makearray[1]{%
    \expandafter\NewDocumentCommand\csname#1\endcsname{r[]g}{%
        \IfValueTF{##2}{%
            \expandafter\def\csname #1@##1\endcsname{##2}%
        }{%
            \csname #1@##1\endcsname
        }%
    }
}

\begin{document}
\makearray{wk}

\wk[1]{this is week 1}
\wk[3]{this is week 3}

\foreach \i in {1,2,3} {\wk[\i]\par}
\end{document}
```

You use it like

```
\makearray{name}
```

to define a new array command `\name`. Then your can use

```
\name[key]{value}
```

to set a value at position `key`, and

```
\name[key]
```

to output the stored value at position `key`. If no key was set before, the result is empty (or equal to `\relax`, to be more precise).

Thus, the output for the above example is

> this is week 1
>   this is week 3

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to want it in contexts of loops, here's an implementation that allows arithmetic expressions in the argument.

I distinguish between the phases of setting and retrieving values. The syntax you propose disallows `\wk` being expandable, because one would have to check whether it is used for setting a value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\wk}{m}
 {
  \prop_item:Nf \g_garth_week_prop { \int_eval:n { #1 } }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\setwk}{mm}
 {
  \prop_gput:Nfn \g_garth_week_prop { \int_eval:n { #1 } } { #2 }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { Nf }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { Nf }

\prop_new:N \g_garth_week_prop

\ExplSyntaxOff

\setwk{2}{This is week two}
\setwk{2+1}{This is week three}

\begin{document}

\wk{2}

\wk{7-2*2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an abstraction layer that allows to define as many arrays as you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\NewArray}{m}
 {
  \prop_new:c { g_garth_#1_prop }
  \cs_new_protected:cpn { set#1 } ##1 ##2
   {
    \prop_gput:cfn { g_garth_#1_prop } { \int_eval:n { ##1 } } { ##2 }
   }
  \cs_new:cpn { #1 } ##1
   {
    \prop_item:cf { g_garth_#1_prop } { \int_eval:n { ##1 } }
   }
 }

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { cf }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_gput:Nnn { cf }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewArray{wk}

\setwk{2}{This is week two}
\setwk{2+1}{This is week three}

\begin{document}

\wk{2}

\wk{7-2*2}

\end{document}
```